# How to use std::sort to sort an array in a 'custom' way, in place

Tags: c++, algorithm

I have an array of floats of size 4N, and I want to sort them by treating each set of 4 floats as a single item - say (x, y, z, w), and then I want to sort them based on the z value.

My current method involves making an array of

```
struct A
{
    float *p;
    int index;

    bool operator < (const A &obj)
    {
        return ( *(p + 2) < *(obj.p + 2) );
    }
};
```

using `std::sort` on it, then creating a new array of size 4N, and filling it according to the corresponding index.

Im sure there is a way to sort it in place, but I cannot figure out how

Comment: If you want to treat "each set of 4 floats as a single item", then this should be an array of items that contain 4 floats each, at which point this becomes a simple custom sort function.

Comment: I dont have control over the data I am given, and its given as an array of floats...

Comment: Am I missing something?  `std::sort` takes a `Compare` parameter, so couldn't you leverage that?

Comment: Create and use a custom iterator class.

Comment: Yup, that'll work, a custom iterator class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this:

```
struct A
{
    float x, y, z, w;

    bool operator < (const A &other) const
    {
        return z < other.z;
    }
};

enum { N = 1000 };
float v[4 * N];
...
A *w = reinterpret_cast<A*>(v);
sort(w, w + N);
```

Comment: hm so I have no doubt this will work on my PC, however i think this might be undefined behavior because of potential struct padding - not sure if someone else can verify though

Comment: Struct padding will be fine on any sane platform, however the strict aliasing crowd could object to the general technique.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define N 55
float *array = new float[4*N];
// fill the array
A* a = reinterpret_cast<A*>(array);
sort(a, a+N);
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this could be done using the [gsl::span](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md#gslspan-what-is-gslspan-and-what-is-it-for) (proposed for standardization). [Here is the SOURCE](https://github.com/Microsoft/GSL/blob/master/include/gsl/span). If you made a vector of *spans* to *overlay* your vector of *floats* you could then sort the *spans* and use the sorted spans as a template to reorder your original values into a new, sorted container.

Something like this:

```
    auto const N = 2;

    std::vector<float> floats = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0};

    assert(floats.size() == 4 * N);

    std::vector<gsl::span<float, 4>> overlays; // spans of 4 floats

    for(auto i = 0U; i < floats.size(); i += 4)
        overlays.emplace_back(&floats[i], 4); // arrange them over the vector

    // sort the spans
    std::sort(std::begin(overlays), std::end(overlays), [](auto a, auto b){
        return a[2] < b[2]; // sort by the third float
    });

    std::vector<float> sorted_floats; // results

    // copy the "contents" of the spans in the correct (sorted)
    // order into the new container
    for(auto const& o: overlays)
        std::copy(std::begin(o), std::end(o), std::back_inserter(sorted_floats));
```

**Note:**

A [gsl::span](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/docs/gsl-intro.md#gslspan-what-is-gslspan-and-what-is-it-for) is not a container in its own right, it simply presents a *window* or *view* into a container. In this example I create a vector of such *windows*, each looking into the original vector and, each *span* being `4` *floats* wide.